# Counting records in one table that match condition in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get a count of the records from table1 which match a category in table2.

Tables could look like this for instance:

```
ID     A          
1      value1   
2      value2
3      value3
4      value2

ID     A        Category
1      value1   Category1
2      value2   Category1
3      value3   Category2
```

Now let's say I want to count the records in Table1 that belong to Category1

The query I came up with:

```
SELECT count(table1.A) as count, table2.Category from table1, table2 
WHERE table2.Category = 'Category1' AND table1.A = table2.A
GROUP BY table2.Category
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Expected result:

```
Category1  3
```

What I get as result:

```
Category1  6
```

The count is the number of times A appears in table1 times the number of times A appears in table2. 
I also tried a LEFT JOIN, but this gives me the same result.

How can I prevent this and just get the count for table1?

Comment: Group by category and remove `A` from the list of columns. The `ORDER BY` also doesn't make sense for one record.

Comment: thx. in my code I grouped by both and tried removing A. Still same result. 
Order by is there to best reflect my code (working wil millions of records;))

Comment: I meant to only group by the category, not by both.

Comment: I tried that, still gives me the same result

Comment: update your question add  the expected  result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use COUNT(DISTINCT) to reduce what it's counting, as long as you use a column that you know is unique in table1.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT table1.id) as count, table2.Category 
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.A = table2.A 
WHERE table2.Category = 'Category1'
GROUP BY table2.Category
ORDER BY count DESC
```

P.S.: Note I also changed this to use modern JOIN syntax. This is not required for the solution, but it's time we stopped using the 1989 comma-style join syntax.